# sendgrid multipart/alternative image from base64

Tags: sendgrid, email-headers

I can't get Sendgrid (using node.js) to send an email with a embedded base64 image in the html. I think I'm quite close...

```
var base64img='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQgAAAFXCAYAAABeLtDdAAAgAElEQVR4Xu19CXhURdb2ISsJgSQ';//shortened version

sendgrid.send({
    to      : 'address1@gmail.com',
    from    : 'address2@gmail.com',
    subject : 'email with image from base64 data',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type':
      'multipart/alternative; boundary="imagebase64"'+
      '--imagebase64'+
      'Content-Type: image/png; name="base64.png"'+
      'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="base64.png"'+
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'+
      'Content-ID: <0123456789>'+
      'Content-Location: base64.png'+
      base64img+
      '--imagebase64'
      },
    html    : '<img src="cid:0123456789"/>'
    });
```

Can someone help, as I'm failing to find an example close on sendgrid docs or google

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***FIXED!***

```
  var base64img='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQgAAAFXCAYAAABeLtDdAAAgAElEQVR4Xu19CXhURdb2ISsJgSQ';//shortened version
  var data=base64img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/,"");
  var buffer=new Buffer(data,'base64');
  fs.writeFile('/home/engine/public_html/img/base64img.png',buffer,function(err){
    fs.readFile('public_html/img/base64img.png',function(err,data){


    sendgrid.send({
      to      : 'address11@gmail.com',
      from    : 'address2@gmail.com',
      subject : 'email with image from base64 data',
      files   : [{filename:'base64.png',content:data,cid:'1234567890'}],
      html    : '<img src="cid:1234567890"/>'
      },
    function(success,message){
      if(!success){console.log(message);}
      else{
        console.log('sent');
        fs.unlink('public_html/img/base64img.png');
        }
    });});});
```

Comment: It _appears_ that some mail servers will strip anything with "data:image/png;base64," at the beginning of it in a sensitive area (eg: an image style tag), maybe it's a filter gone awry that really shouldn't be checking the attachments?